# Need to alert user if user doesnot have Twitter access but try to login through 'SignIn Using Twitter'

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

Facebook and Twitter some where blocked in offices. So our site i need to check before proceed login through facebook or twitter. I checked facebook `FB`is undefined it works. the sameway i need to check twitter. For Twitter i use `codebird.js`. If user doesnot have twitter access. the popup opened and end with 'the Webpage not available'. How can i check before opening this popup.

```
if (typeof(FB) != 'undefined'
             && FB != null ) {
            alert('You havae Facebook Access');
        } else {
            alert('You Dont havae Facebook Access');
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: You could check for twitter's favicon on https://twitter.com/favicon.ico